# print the class of the object(or the source code) that cause null pointer exception in Java

Tags: java, debugging, reflection, nullpointerexception

Let's say there is a **NullPointerException** and I catch it.
Can I somehow retrieve the name of the object that was null?  or 'most probably' was null?
Or even better - retrieving the source code that the exception most likely occurred?

We have a regression with thousands of tests, and many tests fail msg is something like *"NPE in line number.."*
So we need to go to the source code of the test and see what was null... I would like to be able to put this info in the test log and to save us lots of time.
Thanks

Comment: If waiting for and upgrading to [JDK 14](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/14/) is an option (GA is scheduled for 2020/03/17), [JEP 358](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/358) is what you want.

Comment: unfortunately its not. Any other solutions?